# Sprint when energy >= 10, and remove energy each second by x?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am playing around with some FPS Game development within unity and currently have a character able to run, and sprint using these variables:

```
public float regSpeed = 5;
public float sprint = 7;
public int energy = 100;
```

and the following code:

```
var speed = regSpeed;
//Left and Right
MoveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
MoveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(MoveDirection);
MoveDirection *= speed;


//Sprint 
if (energy >= 10 & Input.GetKey("left shift") || Input.GetKey("right shift")){
    MoveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    MoveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(MoveDirection);
    MoveDirection *= sprint;
```

I'm struggling to remove energy each second. I'm guessing I'd use `Time.DeltaTime` or something in a for/while loop to remove X energy each second.

Comment: It's probably more reliable to simply store the `DateTime.Now` object when the sprint begins.  Then, at any point after, you can calculate how much energy is left based on the current `DateTime.Now`.  You can hook up to an event I believe (my Unity is a little rusty) that is fired routinely during movement right?

Comment: Since the only time you would be removing energy is while you are sprinting then why not just decrease energy inside of your sprint code

if (energy >= 10 & Input.GetKey("left shift") || Input.GetKey("right shift")){energy-=5;}

And adjust the amount accordingly till your energy depletes in the time you feel comfortable with in execution time of the game.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the MonoBehaviour.Update() method.  Get the value of Time.deltaTime in each frame and accumulate that value. When the accumulated value is > (1s * 1000ms) decrease the energy. (and reset the accumulated value to cero of course)

Update is called once per frame, probably many more times that you need. I suggest using FixedUpdate() which is called in a fixed rate (not once per frame) to accomplish the same task.

See the differences here
http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/update-and-fixedupdate